# 'AND' in mysql update query

Tags: mysql

I ran the following query on mysql by mistake, and mysql ran it without error:

```
UPDATE table SET col1='value1' AND col2='value2' WHERE ID='id'
```

Thie query should have been

```
UPDATE table SET col1='value1', col2='value2' WHERE ID='id'
```

So my question is: what did the first query with the 'AND' actually do? It seemed to set col1='0' for some reason, which seems strange. Is this just a bug or is this really a valid query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the query actually did:

```
UPDATE table SET col1=('value1' AND col2='value2') WHERE ID='id'
```

Comment: What makes the value `0` ?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Most likely `col2` is not equal to `value2` in this particular row, so the whole expression evaluates to `FALSE` (i.e. `0`)

Comment: `TRUE` is `1` in MySQL and `FALSE` is `0`. So, the `('value1' AND col2='value2')` evaluated to `FALSE` and your `col1` was updated with `0`. The `col2` did not update, correct?